# cityname displaying using javascript autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, mongodb

**code:**

```
 $.ajax({
        url : '/Addbus',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function(data){
        var dt = JSON.parse(data.body);
            $.each(dt,function(i,v){
               $.each(v,function(j,p){
             var arr={};
                 arr= p.name+ ',' +p.id;
                temp.push(arr);
            var result=JSON.stringify(temp);
         console.log(result);

      $("#source").autocomplete({
        source: result, // The source of the AJAX results
        minLength: 3, // The minimum amount of characters that must be typed before the autocomplete is triggered
        focus: function( event, ui ) { // What happens when an autocomplete result is focused on
            $("#source").val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
      },
      select: function ( event, ui ) { // What happens when an autocomplete result is selected
          $("#source").val( ui.item.value );
          $('#source-id').val( ui.item.label );
      }
  });
```

when I select the `cityname` in the textbox then in the `ui.item.value` and `ui.item.label` I am getting the values as
item
:
label
:
"Hyderabad,6"
value
:
"Hyderabad,6",
now how can i seperate them and take in different values.example i want the values as id=6 and name=hyderabad.

Comment: You will get value like <cityname>,<cityId> so you can split it using comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you, don't stringify the results array, use it as an array in source

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/Addbus',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function(data){
        var dt = JSON.parse(data.body);
            $.each(dt,function(i,v){
               $.each(v,function(j,p){
             var arr={};
                 arr.label = p.name;
                 arr.value = p.id;
                temp.push(arr);
            var result=temp

      $("#source").autocomplete({
        source: result, // The source of the AJAX results
        minLength: 3, // The minimum amount of characters that must be typed before the autocomplete is triggered
        focus: function( event, ui ) { // What happens when an autocomplete result is focused on
            $("#source").val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
      },
      select: function ( event, ui ) { // What happens when an autocomplete result is selected
          $("#source").val( ui.item.value );
          $('#source-id').val( ui.item.label );
      }
  });
```

Comment: upto there its fine but my question is how to split the cityname and id in to two variables., it is coming as same , my output is as follows   

["Elurupadu,190", "Sendhwa,1230", "Multai,1262", "Kherwara,1480", "Mandi,2225", "Thamarassery,519", "Ayyampettai,208", "Udaipur,5519",], now on selecting only cityname should be displayed and id should be hidden value

Comment: then put an array like this in source parameter

Comment: [

{

label: "Label",
value: "Value"

}

]

Answer (score 2):

```
const name = ui.item.value.split(',')[0];
const id = ui.item.value.split(',')[1];
```

Comment: by using this im getting the error as   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one...

const name = ui.item.split(',')[0];

const id = ui.item.split(',')[1];